# Laravel with relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an order and transaction model in which 1 order can have many transactions.

However, there are certain areas in which I will only want to return certain rows of the transactions table.

I did something like this:

```
Order::with('transactions')->whereHas('transactions',function($query){
    $query->select(array('A','B'));
}))
```

Where `A` and `B` are the columns of the transactions.

How do I get this to work without changing the name of the relationship?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? You have in `transactions` columns A, B and C and you want to get all rows with columns A and B?

Comment: Put that `select` in the `with` closure, but mind that you **need** to select foreign key.